# Get a value from one method to another method in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the value `vd` from the `b2d()` method into the `main()` function :

```dart
num b2d() {
  var vd = num.parse(dec.text);
  var vb = 0;
  int i = 1;

  while (vd > 0) {
    vb = vb + (vd % 2) * i;
    vd = (vd / 2).floor();
    i = i * 10;
  }

  return vb;
}

void main() {
  print("$vd");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply call `b2d()` in `main()` ?

Comment: I want the value "vb" from b2d() to main().

Comment: Your `b2d()` is returning `vb`, so why not simply call it it `main()` like : `void main() { print("${b2d()}"); }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
void main(){
  var vb = b2d();
  print("$vb") // The value of VB will be here.
}
```